# Custom rewrite rules on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

I have the following url query that is adding the parameter texas and the county harris to the permalink for a query.  These are part of a custom taxonomy called geography.

`xyz.com/dealers/honda/?geography=texas&geography=harris`

How do I rewrite this url in wordpress to be:

`xyz.com/dealers/honda/texas/harris/`

Comment: well for a start that won't work in any site because you've got two params there with the same name... an actually you want to be rewritting the bottom url to BE the top url not the other way round

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the following in your functions.php:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^dealers/honda/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?geography=$matches[1]&geography=$matches[2]','top');
```

However you should note that you have geography set twice and the last one is the one that will be used.

You will also need to navigate to your permalinks page at `xyz.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` before this actually works or else you'll get a 404ish error.

Comment: Thank you for the reply very helpful.  Is there a away to make honda dynamic as I have different brands such as Toyota etc...

Comment: Yup, change `/honda/` to `/[^/]+/`

Comment: Thank you again, one more quick question, i pasted your exact code above in my function.php file for my theme.  You mentioned i need to navigate to the admin permalink, which I did, but what do i need to do when i get there to make this work?

Comment: I just noticed that your wordpress install is not at the root of your server So it might not work the way you want since wordpress needs that rewrite pattern for posts, pages etc. You might want to consider changing your path to `xyz.com/dealers/honda/geo/texas/harris/` and then change the code to `add_rewrite_rule('^dealers/([^/]*)/geo/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','/dealers/$matches[1]/index.php?geography=$matches[2]&geography=$matches[3]','top');` Keep in mind I'm not able to test that code change since I dont have a wordpress install thats not at the root